# Add links using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm trying to add a link at the bottom of google's home page using javascript and greasemonkey in firefox, but I can't make it work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name testing greasemonkey
// @include http://*google.com/
// ==/UserScript==    

document.write('<a href="http://bing.com">Go to Bing</a> ');
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: do you really want to add a link at the bottom of GOOGLE's homepage??

Comment: i find this kinda funny and mean to google at the same time lol

Comment: anyway, i posted an answer...:)

Answer (score 4):

It's probably too late for document.write. Try to add the element to the DOM.

```
var oNewA = document.createElement("a");
oNewA.setAttribute('href', 'http://bing.com');
var oText = document.createTextNode("Go to Bing");
oNewA.appendChild(oText);
document.body.appendChild(oNewA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href="http://bing.com";
link.innerHTML="Go to Bing"
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

For a more useful usage you could do this:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href="http://bing.com";
link.target="_blank";
link.onclick=function() {
  this.href="http://www.bing.com/search?q="+escape(document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value);
}
link.innerHTML="Do the same search in Bing"
document.body.appendChild(link);
```